# Can't access redux' state in components

Tags: react-redux

I made a simple React-Redux based webapp which doesn't work and it should display list of todo. The list of todo is in Redux' state and I need to link it with a UI component to display the data.

Here's my work (link to [github](https://github.com/ru12671012131521222627/study-and-test))

The error is showed up as I run the webapp.

```
TypeError: this.props.getTodoList is not a function
```

It seems like the state of Redux didn't be linked to the props of component.

Did I miss something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to change this line:

```
getTodoList: dispatch(getTodoList())
```

to:

```
getTodoList: () => dispatch(getTodoList())
```

Comment: Thank you, now the webapp doesn't throw the error. but still I can not get "to-do list" from calling "this.props.getTodoList()", I will figure this out. thank you